# Visual Studio 2015 RC Gulp task runner not detecting tasks

Tags: gulp, visual-studio-2015

I have a Gulpfile.js in Visual Studio 2015 RC with a single default task. For some reason it is not showing up in the `Task Runner Explorer`.

I had added gulp to the devDependencies in my `package.json` file and saved it.

Comment: What I've noticed it wants package.json and Gulpfile to be in the project's root. It will auto-install deps after this condition satisfied.

Comment: Restarting VS did not work for me. I just had to add `/// <binding />` to the top of the gulp.js file and it showed up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the release candidate, editing the devDependencies in `package.json` and then saving does not result in the packages being automatically restored/added to the project as I had expected. After saving `package.json` the packages were listed under NPM in the Dependencies node in Solution explorer, but with a caption `"not installed"` next to the package names. Manually invoking `Restore Packages`, as shown in the screenshot, causes Visual Studio to install the pacakges.

After the node modules had been installed the gulp tasks were detected by the `Task Runner Explorer`.

I hope this helps someone else.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to bind the restoration of npm modules and bower components in a Grunt task ? (I would be great because after you can bind it on the Project Open event so that you do not save them in your git repo...)

Comment: I needed to remember to install Gulp locally (-g isn't enough).

Comment: Also, remember to differentiate between project.json and package.json... (similar, but different... the empty project template only adds project.json)

Comment: Can you help me? I added the packages.json and gulfile.js to the root of the solution like some tutorials says, so the appear in Visual Studio inside a Solution Items folder. But I can't see the tasks in the task runner, but also can't see the Dependences item in the solution explorer so I can´t restore packages

Comment: This was my problem - I had been to aggressive cleaning up "devDependencies"! Putting gulp back in here fixed the tasks - they are now shown!

Answer (score 18):

I was also facing the same issue. Just restarted Visual Studio after adding the tasks to gulpfile.js and my problem was solved. All tasks were listed.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For me, Visual Studio crashed while installing the npm modules and it caused corruption in the npm cache.

I had to clean the cache, delete node_modules, and install again.

- Close Visual Studio
- Open node command prompt
- cd [PROJECT_DIR]
- npm cache clean
- rimraf node_modules

  - This will delete the node_modules folder when windows fails because of deep nested paths
  - To install rimraf:
  - npm install rimraf -g
- npm install

Now, open Visual Studio and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Answer taken from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31444245/2305605) about gulp, but this worked for me

> I had the same problem migrating from VS2013 recently. As Josh noted in his comment here Visual Studio 2015 ships with an older version of node. In case you don't want to get stuck with whatever version of node is built into Visual Studio, you can tell it to use the version you have already installed. Go to Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > External Web Tools and reorder locations so that $(PATH) is above $(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External. This also applies to other tools like Grunt, Bower and Gulp.

Answer (score 2):

*This is old question but same issue could be faced by VS 2017 users.*

I was facing same issue in VS 2017 and mistakenly, I had added gulpfile.js in the sub folder.

Make sure gulpfile.js is in the root folder.
[gulpfile should be in root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dPCl.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and no-one of suggested method works for me.
After re-installing NPM Task Runner the problem gone away.
You can download latest NPM Task Runner from marketplace in following link.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.NPMTaskRunner